# Guitar Octave up and down

Tags: guitar, theory

In this link that I have written below,we find E octaves on the Guitar fretbord and my Question is: E note have 8 octaves? and from low E to  E on the 12 fret (6 string)is one octave, and from E on the 12 fret to E (A string) 7 fret second octave but lower from the former and so on and for every note?.. from open high E to 12 fret on this string is 8 octave ? and is up from all? and if 12 frets in one octave how i count them can you show me by this picture of E octave? this link is:

[image: Guitar E notes]

Source: http://visualguitar.com/octave.html

Comment: I think everyone has been trying to help, but it is tricky to understand what you are asking. I understand English may not be your first language, but please try to edit your post to clarify. It may be that you need to look a bit more at the basic theory of western musical notation.

Comment: If nothing else, the chart is a great visual tool to help folks understand that the guitar and similar stringed instruments allow you to play a given pitch in multiple places on the fretboard.

Answer (score 5):

That image only shows three octaves, even though it shows eight different positions on the guitar where one can play an E.

The trick of the diagram is that the E notes that are the same color and are connected in the same line are the **same note**. They are not in different octaves, but exactly the same. So even though there are eight fret positions where you can play an E, there are only four different Es shown in the diagram.

Comment: Good answer but the image actually shows E in FOUR octaves counting the open low E in red, one octave higher in 3 positions shown in orange, two octaves higher in 3 positions shown in yellow and three octaves higher in red.  Counting the Low E I think it's more accurate to say that the E is shown in four different octaves than to say it starts with low E and goes three octaves higher.  So I would say the image shows four octaves since it shows the same note in four different octaves.

Comment: @RockinCowboy I think we are saying the same thing in different ways. I did say there are four different Es and three octaves is the span of the diagram. If it were a keyboard it would be a three octave keyboard with one extra E.

Comment: You are 100% correct.  But OP saw it as 8 octaves.  Explaining that instead of 8 the chart represents an E in 4 "octaves" explains it better from the OP's point of view of refering to each unique E as a new "octave".  So the chart shows not 8 but 4 octaves with three of the octaves shown playable in 3 different places on the fretboard.  But between your answer and my comments (if your edits help reopen the question for posterity), anyone with a similar question in the future will be able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Those are not octaves they are merely three octaves in various positions. The classical guitar generally speaking has a range of three octaves even if there is 72 notes you can play from Low E to 12 fret on high E.

So it looks on average each note has two places on the fret board you can play it, even if there is some with three and some with only one.

Comment: what do you mean `you can play from Low E to 12 fret on high E.` ? You can play higher than that

Comment: The graphic only goes from open strings to fret 12.

Comment: But you said 'Generally speaking'